# Combining several proportion graphs ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, graph, facet-wrap, proportions

I want to create multiple graphs with the same x- and y-axis, using one code.

The graph I want to make has on the y-axis the proportion of people that have 'plaque'. The x-axis contains the age in years. Every graph has a different variable that I am interested in. For example: ethnicity (H1_EtnTotaal), Sex (H1_geslacht) or smoking (H2_Roken).
Now, I manage to plot these graphs seperate. However, I like to have them combined in one figure (so multiple small graphs, each graph containing te association between variable of interest/proportion of plaque).

The code I now use is:

```
A <- Dataset %>%
  group_by(H2_lft, H1_EtnTotaal) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(Plaque_presence == "Yes")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H2_lft, y = p, fill = H1_EtnTotaal)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Ethnicity") +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic()
A + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Proportion of plaque", title = "Plaque presence", caption = "Figure 2: Proportion of participants with plaque") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

B <- Dataset %>%
  group_by(H2_lft, H1_geslacht) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(Plaque_presence == "Yes")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H2_lft, y = p, fill = H1_geslacht)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Sex") +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic()
B + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Proportion of plaque", title = "Plaque presence", caption = "Figure 2: Proportion of participants with plaque") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

C <- Dataset %>%
  group_by(H2_lft, H2_Roken) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(Plaque_presence == "Yes")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H2_lft, y = p, fill = H2_Roken)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Smoking") +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic()
C + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Proportion of plaque", title = "Plaque presence", caption = "Figure 2: Proportion of participants with plaque") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))

D <- Dataset %>%
  group_by(H2_lft, Hypertension) %>%
  summarise(p = mean(Plaque_presence == "Yes")) %>%
  ggplot(aes(x = H2_lft, y = p, fill = Hypertension)) +
  scale_fill_discrete(name = "Hypertension") +
  geom_smooth(se = TRUE) +
  scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 1)) +
  theme_classic()
D + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Proportion of plaque", title = "Plaque presence", caption = "Figure 2: Proportion of participants with plaque") + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5))
```

I get several graphs, but I want them combined in one figure.

For another graph I made (x-axis: age, y-axis: IMT) and again several variables of interest, someone helped me with this problem by doing:

```
new <- tidyr::pivot_longer(Dataset, c(H1_EtnTotaal, H2_Roken, H1_geslacht, Diabetes_GLUC_MED))

ggplot(new, aes(H2_lft, MeanIMT_alg, group = value)) +
    geom_smooth(
        data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H1_EtnTotaal"),
        aes(colour = value), 
        se = TRUE
    ) +
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "Ethnicity") +
    new_scale_colour() +
    geom_smooth(
        data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H1_geslacht"),
        aes(colour = value),
        se = TRUE
    ) +
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "Sex") + 
    new_scale_colour() +
    geom_smooth(
        data = ~ subset(.x, name == "H2_Roken"),
        aes(colour = value),
        se = TRUE
    ) +
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "Smoking") + 
    new_scale_colour() +
    geom_smooth(
        data = ~ subset(.x, name == "Diabetes_GLUC_MED"),
        aes(colour = value),
        se = TRUE
    ) +
    scale_colour_discrete(name = "Diabetes") +
    new_scale_colour() +
    geom_smooth(
        method = lm, se = TRUE,
        aes(group = NULL)
    ) +
    facet_wrap(~ name) + theme_classic() + theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5)) + labs(x = "Age (years)", y = "Mean IMT (mm)", title ="IMT", caption = "Figure 2: association between cardiovascular risk factors and IMT", color = "cardiovascular risk factors", fil = "cardiovascular risk factors")
```

This however does not seem to work with my graph of proportion of plaque.

Can somebody help me?

Thanks in advance!! :)

Kind regards, Marleen

Comment: When your faceting starts to get complex, with (for example) variables of different types on the same axis, it makes sense to use patchwork::wrap_plots() instead of ggplot2::facet_wrap.

Comment: Thank you so much! This seems to be it :)

Comment: Greetings! Usually it is helpful to provide a minimally reproducible dataset for questions here so people can troubleshoot your problems. One way of doing this is by using the `dput` function. You can find out how to use it here: https://youtu.be/3EID3P1oisg